# Why are my object value definitions not working? (returning undefined)

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, undefined-reference

So I am creating a Discord bot using discord.js (not that that has anything to do with the problem, though it might help understanding).

I have a function `handle` which handles incoming commands.

```js
var sgs = {};
var handle = function(msg){
    var gid = msg.guild.id; // msg.guild.id is a string 

    console.log(gid); // works as expected

    sgs[gid] = "plz omg"; 
    console.log(sgs[gid]); // returns undefined

    sgs.plz = "hi";
    console.log(sgs.plz); // returns undefined

    if(sgs[gid] == undefined){
        sgs[gid] = "sadness";
        console.log(sgs[gid]); // returns undefined
    }
    console.log(sgs); // returns an empty object
}
```

I have tried using `sgs.gid` instead of `sgs[gid]`, to no avail. I'm not exactly sure what's going on here.

(Also, if there's anything wrong with how I phrased, formatted, or asked this question, please tell me, this is like my second question here.)

Comment: There's something you're missing because this works as expected when everything is as you say it is ~ https://jsfiddle.net/Lhk5wnxt/

Comment: Because `sgs` is declared and accessible outside of your handler, it’s possible something else is resetting it before your `console.log` executes. `console.log` does not necessarily run synchronously.

Comment: @Phil , oh, you're right. The one thing I left out (because I didn't realize it was related) was that I had an ```fs.readFile()``` which was what set the value of ```sgs``` to be an empty object, though I'm not sure why it wouldn't allow me to set values to it (since it still returned an empty object, even after the fs.readFile() thing).

Comment: @rat hatfield oh yes, you're right! As in my previous comment, ```fs.readFile()``` runs asynchronously, meaning it gets reset after all the declarations. I'll use ```fs.readFileSync()``` instead. Thanks.

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous so if you're passing it a callback function, that will execute at a **later** time. Try `fs.readFileSync`

Comment: @Phil , yep, thanks!